# Determine the p:autoComplete component who invoked the bean method

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I have two PrimeFaces `<p:autoComplete>` components in a facet, each is identified by an `id` attribute and their `completeMethod` methods are bound to the same managed bean method. I can't change these 2 method bindings.

I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve the `id` of the `<p:autoComplete>` component who called the managed bean method in order to make different treatments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) to obtain the currently processing component from the EL scope.

```
UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
// ...
```

It allows you to use e.g. [`UIComponent#getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId%28%29) to determine the component ID.